# Include tag not displaying

Tags: html, jsf, include, xhtml, facelets

I've been learning about facelets, and I can't seem to get a simple `<ui:include>` tag to work.
I have the following xhtml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head />
<body>
<f:view>
    <h:form>
        <ui:include src="header.xhtml" />
        Body text here.
    </h:form>
</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

and the following is header.xhtml (in the same directory):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head />
<body>
<ui:composition>
    <h2>Our Company</h2>
</ui:composition>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I open the first file in Chrome, the `<h2>Our Company<\h2>` does not display. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `<ui:include src="./header.xhtml" />`

Comment: Rightclick page in webbrowser and do *View Page Source*. What exactly do you see there? Do you see exactly the raw source code of main XHTML file, or is it parsed and do you see the generated HTML output with all `f:xxx`, `h:xxx` and `ui:xxx` tags removed?

Comment: Changing to <ui:include src="./header.xhtml" /> didn't work. I see the raw source code of the main XHTML file.
Thank you both for the help

Comment: .. so it's not just the `<ui:include>` that doesn't work, but the `<f:view>` etc too?

Comment: I not sure I understand your question. The "Body text here." text displays correctly, so that would mean the f:view is doing something, correct?